# Can not import theano in vscode by python

Tags: python, python-theano

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBSnK.png)
on windows10,vscode,py39 is my virtual environment.

have tried upgrade numpy and reinstall theano,conda list is ok.
import numpy and import theano still not work.

version
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwcPy.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you post a question please provide much information, code snippets if possible and an accurate explanation of your problem. Also check if your question was already asked before. [How To: Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)